# how to run psql commands in exec in java

Tags: java, kubernetes, psql

I'm trying to execute psql commands using exec kubernetes java client API, for example:

```
final Process proc = exec.exec(pod,  new String []{"sh", "-c",  "su  postgres -c 'psql -c 'SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata';'"} , true, true);
```

for some reason I get no results as output, it just prints this:

```
--
(1 row)
```

Even though when I simply use kubectl exec directly the SELECT commands return the results correctly.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nesting single quotes doesn’t work.  Why are you using  `sh -c` at all?  Why not just `new String[] { "su", "postgres", "-c", "psql -c 'SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata'" }`?

Comment: I thought they're necessary  .. thanks a lot!